# Unable to reference external file using PhoneGap Build

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm unable to reference external files (CSS/JavaScript) when they are located at a parent folder of the HTML file using [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com).

The following example works fine:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="teste.css" />
```

But if the move the file to a parent level it doens't load it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../teste.css" />
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./../teste.css" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've debbuged the application using weinre and noticed that PhoneGap considered root as the folder where index.html was located

That being said, I've refactored the structure of my web application in order to index.html be located  on the parent folder.

Comment: so how does it works? if you have index.html in www folder cans you have an other folder www/js and put your file in it? and you refer to this page with href="/js/file.js"?

Answer (score 0):

just a guess but, so if you're using jQuery mobile, im assuming you're using the ajax as part of that. Now if that ajax is loading a page in to another page that is on the root of your app that means that technically that page no longer lives in a sub folder, thus the file should just reference the parent css as it would if it were on the root. Make sense?

so rather than

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../teste.css" />
```

just keep

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="teste.css" />
```

Comment: I'm not loading a page in to another page. My page is currently at a sub-folder and I want to reference external files that are located at a parent level.

Comment: Android. I used weinre to debug the application and noticed that PhoneGap assumes the folder of the page as root and therefore I can't access to top levels due to security questions. This means that I cannot have the page in a sub-folder?

Comment: hmm, I always set my apps up like this - (www -> index.html | JS | CSS | images | pages) inside of pages I have sub pages that I am easily able to reference files in CSS and images, BUT I am using ajax to load those pages into my index.html so it could be that nested pages have an issue